# I need to match a font from a designer to something similar for web

Tags: css, layout, fonts

I don't know if this is an Illustrator spec or where exactly, but a designer gave me this spec for a font:

> Helvetica Neue (T1),  35 thin,  20 pt,  off/ 454545, on/70a63a

There are other similar ones for different areas of the page, but if you can tell me how to match this one using CSS, hopefully I can figure out the rest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you as close as possible on all platforms:

```
font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:100;
font-size:20pt;
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be difficult as only a SMALL subset of fonts are supported by all browsers, and MAY look completely different in one browser as opposed to another (see Fantasy type font in Firefox vs IE).

Here is some css to get you started though

```
.myCss {font-family:Helvetica;font-size:20pt;font-weight:100;color:#454545}
.myCss:hover {color:#70a63a}
```

Font-weight, in current browsers supports pretty much NORMAL and BOLD.  But in new browsers will range from 100 to 900, with 700 being todays BOLD, and 400 being todays NORMAL.

NOTE: Hover will only work on link elements in stupid IE 6, support for it is MUCH better in IE 7 and waaay better in firefox.

Comment: Thanks. Don't know why I was thinking pt doesn't work in css... Is Helvetica the same as Helvetica Neue (T1)?

Comment: @joe it's not, but very few end users have helvetica neue on their computer. Helvetica is the closest substitute (see my answer)

Comment: Yeah, you can put Helvetica Neue, then Helvetica, so those users who DO support Helvetica Neue on their browsers will see it.

Answer (score 1):

The font name is Helvetica Neue. The T1 means PostScript type 1. 35 Thin is the weight/variation. 20 pt is the size. off and on are the colors.

Helvetica Neue (or Helvetica or Arial--all three are very similar) is present on just about every computer. The thin variation is not. I recommend doing font family Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, font-size: 20pt, and setting the font weight to the lowest possible: 100. Some variations of Helvetica/Arial may not have lighter font-weight variations, so setting the font-weight may not do anything.

If you absolutely need the exact font (and if your designer expects this in anything but headings when designing for the web, you need to go have a talk with said designer), you can use [SIFR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Inman_Flash_Replacement) or images.

Comment: is helvetica/helvetica neue really that commonly installed?

Comment: Helvetica and Helvetica Neue is installed on OS X by default. Also with any high-end Adobe products, and also with a lot of font packs/other programs that come with a lot of fonts. I wouldn't say it's present on a majority of computers by any stretch of the imagination, but depending on your audience it may be 20-30% or even higher. High enough to use it as a default in my opinion, since it *is* a nicer than Arial.

Comment: The designer's cool actually. It is only for headings, he totally gets that it may not be precise and is willing to make images if need be. He's not one of those difficult guys thank G_d :)

Wish I could mark all 3 as the answer because I learned something from each & the comments were helpful too.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could be helpful.